# using mod_rewrite with XAMPP and windows 7 - 64 bit?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, xampp

i have a simple mod_rewrite rule which allow me to re-direct any requests that are not actual files or directories to the index.php file

```
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

in PHP file i put this simple code to handle this navigation

```
<?php
$navString = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Returns "/Mod_rewrite/edit/1/"
$parts = explode('/', $navString); // Break into an array
// Lets look at the array of items we have:
print_r($parts);
?>
```

my development environment is XAMPP and Windows 7 - 64 bit
httpd.conf file

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

my problem is when ever i pass any varible to the scrip for example

```
http://locahost/test/somethinghere/andhere
```

it redirect me to the local host default page which is

```
http://locahost/xampp
```

Comment: is your xampp context set up as a single host (e.g. everything in http://localhost) or are you using virtual hosts?

Comment: @zamnuts i think its using VirtualHost but its auto manage because all of wordpress and other scripts re-write rules are working with no problem

Comment: i don't think i can help you without seeing your httpd.conf and your virtual host configuration.

Comment: check this link http://only4ututorials.blogspot.com/2017/04/how-to-enable-modrewrite-in-xammp.html

Answer (score 16):

Below are the instructions on how to enable .htaccess mod_rewrite in xampp.

1. Open and edit C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf in a text editor
2. Find the line which contains

   ```
   #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```

   and (uncomment) change to

   ```
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
   ```
3. Find all occurrences of

   ```
   AllowOverride None
   ```

   and change to

   ```
   AllowOverride All
   ```
4. Restart xampp

That’s it you should be good to go.

Help: http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/

Answer (score 4):

Solved
i just added the folder to the .htaccess and remove Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

```
RewriteBase /test/
```

Comment: XAMPP Windows 7.  Where is the .htaccess file?

Comment: Tried so many, much more complex variations, but actually, this was the answer for me as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A rewrite rule can be enabled through in **httpd.conf** or in **.htaccess** file.
    Instructions on how to enable **.htaccess mod_rewrite** in wamp/xampp
    **Step 1:** Go to the directory of installation :
    `C:\xampp>\apache\conf`
    or `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf`
    **Step 2:** Open **httpd.conf** in a text editor
    **Step 3:** Find the line which contains
         `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
    **Step 4:** Remove (#) from start of line to make module enable
    **Step 5:** Now Change all occurrences of `AllowOverride None`
         and replace to `AllowOverride All`
    **Step 6:** Now restart **wamp/xampp** server