# clean URL test failed D7

Tags: php, drupal, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I have spent about four hours trying to get clean URLs to work and it is really doing my head in. I am *very* new to Drupal and after hearing all the wonderful things about it, this is disappointing. Here is my setup:

I have `XAMPP on windows 7`, and installed `Drupal 7.22` into a folder `c:\code\drupal`

In my `httpd.conf`, I have `Alias /code "C:\code"` This works because I have other folders inside `c:\code` functioning perfectly well

The `drupal .htaccess` file works because if I add junk line in there I get a server error

In the `.htaccess` I tried all combinations of `RewriteBase` I could think of:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteBase /code
RewriteBase /code/drupal
RewriteBase /drupal
```

`mod_rewrite` works because I already have other installations which uses it correctly.

I also tried going directly to `http://localhost/code/drupal/admin/config/search/clean-urls` but that gives me a `404 error`

Every time I go back to `admin > config > clean URLS`, it says the test failed. I know this is apparently some error from my side, but its getting very frustrating. Can anyone see what I am missing here? :(

- I read all the similar questions here in SO, but their solutions do
  not work for me.
- I posted this in `drupal.stackexchange.com` as well
  but did not get any answers.
- I am posting it here since the SO PHP
  community is more active and undoubtedly there are many who know
  drupal in depth.
- I am really hoping someone will help me figure this out...

Comment: If you look at the error log where the petition for that host is displayed, is the URL being rewritten? Or is it asking for the url without giving it the rewrite rule?

Comment: It is going without rewrite rule. It hits the drupal page with regular URL and a gives 200 response. The regular URL gives a message saying rewrite cannot be enabled. The online docs suggested all the stuff that I tried above in my question - but to no avail. And the entry is in access.log not error.log since there are no errors per se..

Comment: Try to replace entire .htaccess with something pretty simple like `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://google.com` Is it redirecting you to google.com? Also you can try to write log files for rewrite module, just add to your httpd.conf file following: `RewriteLog "/home/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9` Maybe there will be something interesting in logs  :)

Comment: @tulvit: Thanks for the suggestions. 1) Yes, it redirects to google.com. 2) I added line to httpd.conf, restarted server and tried accessing urls, but the file rewrite.log is not getting created. error.log does not say anything about it either...

Comment: Actually - I was wrong, it is creating rewrite.log (I gave nonexistant file path). Let me check that and get back in a few! Thanks heaps, you rock!!!

Comment: Rather strange... Last time I have problems with mode rewrite in Drupal `RewriteBase /` did the trick, but you've already tried it( I hope you change `"/home/rewrite.log"` to the real path (it should be something like C:/logs in Windows, I guess), if so I have no clue why log file have not been created. /Oh, you've already changed path! =) By the way, this logs didn't help me a lot last time I've used them, but I hope it'll be quite helpful in your case =)

Comment: Yeah, the log gets created but not much help. When I go to localhost/code/drupal - it makes entry about all the rewrites and the page also gets loaded, but when I go to any other page with clean URL and get a 404, the rewrite log does not say anything. Oh well....I am not sure if Drupal & I are going to get along... :)

Comment: Just have find this article [Clean URLs with XAMPP](http://drupal.org/node/43545), but I guess you've already read it. And according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272731/using-mod-rewrite-with-xampp-and-windows-7-64-bit/12273060#12273060) maybe `RewriteBase /drupal/` will work (with additional slash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you still need help, but I spent good amount of time trying to figure that out myself a while ago and couldn't find the right answer. After doing a lot of trial and error, I made it work. I don't know exactly how your setup is but here is how mine is, as well as my solution on [drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/2007870).

(Here is a copy of a part of my original question and my complete solution)

> Hi,
>
> I have a Drupal multisite setup and I am trying to make the Clean URLs
>   work but cannot seem to be able to write the conditions and rules
>   properly. I have found many answers but none of them worked.
>
> My .htaccess file is being read without problem and the rules are
>   being used (I tried setting the rewrite rule to the full address but
>   it was only giving me the home page and I couldn't go anywhere else).
>
> Here is how it is setup:
>
> DEV: URL1 www.site1.domain.fr/dev 
>            URL2 www.site2.site1.domain.fr/dev
>
> PROD URL1 www.site1.domain.fr 
>              URL2 www.site2.site1.domain.fr
>
> On the server: /dev (one drupal install) 
>                          /prod (another drupal install
>   but same content)
>
> My multisite is setup as this: 
>   /sites/site1.domain.fr 
>   /sites/site2.site1.domain.fr (same thing for dev and for prod)
>
> Inside sites.php:
>
> ```
> $sites = array( 
>  'www.site1.domain.fr' => 'site1.domain.fr', 
>  'www.site2.site1.domain.fr' => 'site2.site1.domain.fr', )
> ```

Solution

> I was finally able to fix it by trial and error. In case any of you
>   encounter the same problem, here is how I fixed it:

```
DEV: 

RewriteBase /dev

# Main site 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.domain\.fr [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site1.domain.fr/dev/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# Site 2 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2.site1\.domain\.fr [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site2.site1.domain.fr/dev/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]


PROD: 

RewriteBase /

# Main site 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1\.domain\.fr [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site1.domain.fr/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# Site 2 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2.site1\.domain\.fr [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site2.site1.domain.fr/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Instead of linking to your solution, can you describe it here? Otherwise there's not a lot of substance to your answer and it could suffer link rot.

Comment: Here I added it. Sorry it took a while everything got stuck together when I pasted it.

Comment: @CarolineCB - I realized I never marked your answer as correct! Well...its almost a year too late, but still - thanks!