# How to run a php file from root directory in xampp upon loading?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

[image]

I want to load the **draft.php** file when i type the address in browser: **localhost:81/mvcdemo** .I have added this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ draft.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have also changed **Apache(httpd.config)** file to get the rewrite on. So, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why not call it index.php? That's what's usually configured to load by default anyway.

Comment: @some-non-descript-user I know that. I just want to figure it out what is wrong with my rewriting?

Comment: Your `.htaccess` seems fine. Double check your config, also don't forget to restart Apache after making changes. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272731/using-mod-rewrite-with-xampp-and-windows-7-64-bit) for more help with the config.

Comment: You're rewrite config looks fine to me. Are you sure that mod_rewrite is active? What does the log file say?

Comment: @harris i've done all of those things. I can't figure it out what is going wrong. It works if i use 'index.php' but that's just the default.

Answer (score 2):

You have conditions defined so that your `RewriteRule` will only be triggered, if the requested file, directory or link does not exist.

So if your `.htaccess` file is inside the directory `mvcdemo` and you're requesting said directory, the rule will not be triggered, because the directory exists.

Requesting `http://localhost:81/mvcdemo/foo` should trigger the rewrite rule, as it doesn't exist.

If you want all requests to the directory to be rewritten, then you can just do away with the conditions:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ draft.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that `RewriteBase /` sets the base URL as the document root, and since `draft.php` seems to be in the `mvcdemo` directory itself,  you should do away with, as it will result in a `draft.php` not found error.

Answer (score 0):

You could change apache's `DirectoryIndex` directive in your config file (or via an .htaccess) and append draft.php. Then it's auto-loaded like the usual index.html or index.php files.

Comment: Can you help me how to do this by rewriting?