# remove requirement of index.php in url for loading controller- PHP xamp

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I am totally new to Code igniter and dealing with form submissions through MVC archi. As, I searched and tried all soultions and code given on stack overflow itself to remove index.php from url but all of them didn't worked. I know something is missing and I am not able to recognize it as I am new to CI.

This is my .htaccess code below,

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all denied
</IfModule>

<IfModule !authz_core_module>
Deny from all
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have also set $config['index_page']=' '; and $config['uri_protocol']='REQUEST_URI'; in config.php file.

**NOTE: My CI version is 3x**

Comment: you're working on your local server? which OS?

Comment: yes i am working on win10 OS ..

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272731/using-mod-rewrite-with-xampp-and-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: Your htaccess is not right

Comment: @AnandPandey any solution for that?

Comment: I will give you the right htaccess

Comment: @AnandPandey yess plz..

Comment: Check my answer and make sure the base_url is also right

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your rewrite base is right like given in screen shot i have given. There are many htaccess files in each folder. I give the htaccess which is in red in the image and the structure also.

[image]

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
      #  slashes.
      # If your page resides at
      #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
      # then use
      # RewriteBase /projectfolder  //its an example

      RewriteBase /project
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
      # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
      # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
      # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
      ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/'  in the application/config/config.php

Comment: Glad to help samrat bhai

Answer (score 1):

I use xampp and windows 10

Place in main directory of project not in the application folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

Structure

```
application
system
user_guide
.htaccess
index.php
```

Try some of these also

https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Don't for get to set base_url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```